# Paste Special in Excel as standard

Tags: excel, paste, vba

Is there a way where I can make an Excel file where whenever you copy something from it then it will automatically use paste special formatted as values? Even if you paste in another Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution where I run a on-key event macro which looks like this:

```
Sub Paste_Special()
  On Error Resume Next

If Err = 1004 Then
  Exit Sub
Else
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And it works between Excel files as long as the file where the macro originate from is open.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the paste special icon to the quick access toolbar, then it is available in any spreadsheet.  As a bonus this becomes easily accessible by a keyboard shortcut as well, just press ALT and the given alphanumeric.  See the images below.

When you copy, the information is passed into to clipboard but, AFAIK, there is no way to pass a parameter let alone have that modify the paste function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know but then I'll have to tell all the other people who use my excel sheet to do this or use the shortcut which is kind of inconvenient.

Comment: Not much you can do as all solutions will require some user training.  

The only other thing I would propose is to include the following macro `Sub Paste_Values()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False End Sub` in your file, save it as macro enabled, assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut (e.g. CTRL+SHIFT+V) then give instructions to your users.   (I have this macro saved in my personal.xlsm file as I use it all the time.)

Comment: Yeah, this is a good beginning on what I want to achieve but nonetheless I'm still looking to optimise this.